# Filling matrix with "Dynamic" number of rows, by rows

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a matrix M, which has 3 columns, but an unknown number of rows (num) that depend on the inputs to a function. I would like to fill this matrix by row in a for loop, as follows:

```
Matrix<double, Dynamic, 3> M;
for(int iter = 0; iter < num; iter++){
Vector3d x;
x << 1,2,3;
M.row(iter) = x.transpose();}
```

this doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?.
The error message I get is the following:

```
Assertion failed: ((i>=0) && ( ((BlockRows==1) && (BlockCols==XprType::ColsAtCompileTime) && i<xpr.rows()) ||((BlockRows==XprType::RowsAtCompileTime) && (BlockCols==1) && i<xpr.cols()))), function Block, file /usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Block.h, line 122.
```

EDIT
Keep in mind that the following throws no errors at all, since the number of rows and columns of M have been defined (4 and 3):

```
Matrix<double,4,3> M ;
Vector3d x;
x << 1,2,3;
M.row(0) = x.transpose();
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: @JohnFilleau I updated it now. I was running this on MATLAB using MEX, and matlab would simply crash. I updated my question including the error message I get from the C++ compiler.

Comment: I don't know eigen but `x << 1,2,3;` is suspicious. This should evaluate as `(((x << 1),2),3)`. The `,2` and `,3` would then do nothing. Unless eigen somehow overload `operator,` which well, would be mind-boggling but maybe not unheard of...

Comment: @Jeffrey Eigen overloads `operator,` to allow assigning vectors thusly.

Comment: You need to actually allocate `M`, like: `Matrix<double, Dynamic, 3> M(rows, 3);`

Comment: @chtz thank you, that worked. Thanks to all for participating